# ivy preview buffer without buffer creation

Tags: buffers, ivy, counsel

When searching in a project using a `counsel-ag`, I want to implement a preview, similar to the `counsel-grep`.
Now I use copy-paste from `counsel-ag` with

```
:update-fn (lambda ()
            (counsel-grep-action (ivy-state-current ivy-last)))
```

But it opens too much buffers when I navigate in result buffer.
How I can implement result preview without opening buffer? I don't need to have buffer with result if it does not exists or before I open result manually.